# Fig 1a into Fig 1a (but with "a" is in \textit)

Tags: floats, subfloats, ref

```
   \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{subcaption}
    

   \begin{document}

   \begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
   \begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
     \caption{ \textit{a} }
     \label{1a}
   \end{subfigure}%
   \begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=.715\linewidth]{example-image-b}
     \caption{ \textit{b} }
     \label{1b}
   \end{subfigure}
   \caption{ }
   \label{fig1}
   \end{figure}

   I have Fig. \ref{1a}

   \end{document}
```

I need

[image]

**Full source:** https://ru.overleaf.com/5964955496qykytjbjtbgx

Comment: Use ` \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\itshape\alph{subfigure}}` in the preamble.

Comment: @Imran Thank You very much but I expressed myself not quite correctly, because as you can see by clicking on the link I use a template with many parameters and something does not work correctly with your command and everything that after it becomes \italic too

Comment: Oh, sorry! It need to be enclosed. Use `renewcommand\thesubfigure{{\itshape\alph{subfigure}}}`

Comment: @Imran yes, thank You very much, it works
Please post Your comment as the answer, I'll mark it as useful and close question.

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh: So you want to change the subfigure numbering to *italics* everywhere? Not just in the reference, but also in the actual subfigure `\caption`, correct?

Comment: @Werner It would be great to learn how to change the numbering style "only " in reference. Will you please post an answer here or should I ask a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Comment changed into answer.)

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{{\itshape\alph{subfigure}}} %<--- added

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
         \caption{ \textit{a} }
         \label{1a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.715\linewidth]{example-image-b}
         \caption{ \textit{b} }
         \label{1b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{ }
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

I have Fig. \ref{1a} text text

\end{document}
```

[image]